# Dirichlet-like distribution for $\sum_k X_k^2 = 1$

Tags: normalization, dirichlet-distribution

Normally a Dirichlet distribution outputs a vector of $Dir(\alpha_{1...k})=X_i|_{i=1}^k\in [0,1]$, where $\sum_k X_k = 1$.

Is there a similar distribution that can be created for $Y_i|_{i=1}^k\in [-1,1]$, where $\sum_k Y_k^2 = 1$?  I've thought about just doing $Y_i=\pm\sqrt{X_i}$, but this means having to have a separate distribution for the signs and adding another covariance.

Purpose is to have a way to quantify the statistical variation of unit vectors or unit quaternions.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises%E2%80%93Fisher_distribution may be what you're looking for.

Comment: It's close, but implies a single bias direction instead of a orthotropic bias.  Even a [Kent Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kent_distribution) doesn't seem to be able to handle a ring distribution.

Comment: Although I guess there's nothing technically stopping me from making $\kappa<0$ for ring distributions, is there?

Comment: Ordinarily one does not "quantify statistical variation" by assuming some distribution.  Instead, an appropriate distribution is either (a) derived from theoretical considerations concerning the phenomenon being studied and/or (b) estimated from data.  Since you haven't described a phenomenon or data, it's hard to see how your question could be answered.  Perhaps you could offer more information?